# Operations management software for design and installation team

Tags: web-apps, project-management, mobile, asset-management

A client of mine is in the audio/visual/control system integration market, he's looking for a software that he can define business rules like:

- Needed materials and cost for each job
- Needed tools and associated rental cost or wear and tear cost for each job
- Time it usually take for each of the job to be completed

and the software should help him to answer these questions:

- I'm going to vendor A today, what do I need to buy from vendor A?
- What material and tools should be on the truck before heading out today?

I'm not even sure what software like this is called and don't know how to search for it. My client is asking me to develop it for him, I personally would prefer to find existing solutions over custom development. It will probably be cheaper for my client and have better support in the future as well.